# Find the last value in an array with AMPscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

How can I find the last value in an array using AMPscript. I know I can call positions like 1, 2, 3 etc and it will return the values corresponding to those positions but how can I call the last value? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since there are no arrays in AMPScript (just rowsets), you can just use the [**rowcount()**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/content_ampscript_functions2/rowcount/) to find the last element:

```
%%[
var @arr, @e, @arrPos, @count, @lastVal

set @arr = "red|yellow|black|white|green"
set @e = BuildRowsetFromString(@arr,"|")
set @count = rowcount(@e)

if @count > 0 then

    set @arrPos = row(@e, @count) /* get row last element */
    set @lastVal = field(@arrPos,1)
    outputline(concat("<br>lastVal: ",@lastVal))

else

  outputline(concat("<br>empty array"))

endif
]%%
```

Comment: this works Adam, thanks a lot. Some of these values are repeating, how can I find how many of the @lastVal are?

Comment: You can iterate through the elements with a for-loop.  I have some examples on my blog here that can be altered to use row-sets from strings: http://sprignaturemoves.com/ampscript-lookup-examples/

Comment: that works, thanks again. Now the problem is, I need to show the email content at the time of sent but in the view online they change because the ampscript runs again. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Check out this _messagecontext personalization string